# Default Web app bot not working in test in web chat

Tags: botframework, bots

I have created a web app bot in the azure portal but when I try to test it in 'test in web chat' option, its giving an error “couldn’t send”. Below are some other key points:

1. Its created using NodeJS v4 template option.
2. Azure account is an organizational account integrated with Azure AD.
3. I get the same error even if I create an echo bot basic bot or any other bot.

Observation:

1. The Microsoft app  is created internally while creating the bot service with the option “account type” as “ account in this organisational directory only”.
2. If I create the app with “account type” option "account in any organisational directory and personal Microsoft account", then the bot is working fine .

As per the organizational policy, I can only move ahead with creating the account type as “ account in this organisational directory only”. What should be the fix to make it work with this option ?

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting in the dev console when you try to 'test in web chat'? Also, check if you have the the permission in your own organization(ask your admin if you have restricted access).

Comment: Exact error I will check and post but for permission can you please confirm what type of permission I should check ..are h talking about some explicitly permission on app ? Also please note that I am to successfully test and app that I created few months back and the issue is only with new bot that I create so I am not sure if it’s about permission at organisational level

Comment: What value are you entering for Tenant ID?

Comment: Where exactly we need to enter tenant Id, since I am just creating a simple web app bot using steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0, I believe only application ID is used and not the tenant ID.

Comment: When you say account type, where do you get the option to select the account type? Also, if you could post what error you are getting in the dev console, it would be helpful to narrow down the issue.